# Replace the NAs of 1 daframe by imputing Values from the second in R

Tags: r, dplyr

There are many ways of getting NAs imputed and I have gone through these a few of them listed as below

[1 conditional replace using match ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716163/conditional-replace-using-match-of-column-row-names-from-other-data-frame)

[2 Replacing NA values from another  ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010196/replacing-na-values-from-another-dataframe-by-id)

[3 Replacing values from a column ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871614/replacing-values-from-a-column-using-a-condition-in-r)

But my query is a bit different and that is due to the shape of dataframe that is quite different in the 2 given below.

The question is very simple: How to replace the missign`NAs` of one dataframe from the values that are present in another dataframe.
The restrictions are here that I am not interested in reshaping the data otherwise the links which I have shared have the solutions that can be implemented.

All I want that for each NA the colname and rowname be identified from `fd2` and based on that reference value the value from `fd1` columns of `Year` and `Area` be picked and placed.
thanks

I am putting below the first dataframe that has the missing `NAs` as first.

```
    fd2 <- structure(list(Area = c("Australia", "Canada", "France", "Russia", 
"USA"), `2001` = c(NA, 17658856L, 15621317L, NA, 25782618L), 
    `2002` = c(14697182L, NA, 13678411L, NA, 24245829L), `2003` = c(NA, 
    11703543L, 16366886L, NA, 25429428L), `2004` = c(18450822L, 
    15118679L, NA, NA, 31581449L), `2005` = c(NA, 13924960L, 
    16022528L, NA, 27178553L), `2006` = c(NA, 18497809L, 16580501L, 
    NA, 23377178L), `2007` = c(NA, 17551674L, NA, 14444108L, 
    32946902L), `2008` = c(NA, 15781400L, 16292571L, NA, 30093351L
    ), `2009` = c(NA, 19279098L, 16872217L, NA, 21942248L), `2010` = c(NA, 
    18394492L, 21081540L, NA, 27629318L), `2011` = c(17657181L, 
    NA, 20345934L, NA, 32789893L), `2012` = c(23535862L, 17866820L, 
    NA, NA, 25769493L), `2013` = c(NA, 19808018L, 19638502L, 
    NA, 33198288L), `2014` = c(NA, 24189370L, NA, 22139263L, 
    25645749L), `2015` = c(NA, 23610801L, NA, 21234225L, 21268696L
    ), `2016` = c(NA, 19702348L, NA, 25326784L, 24041586L), `2017` = c(21985914L, 
    NA, NA, 33025971L, 27299214L), `2018` = c(NA, 22874184L, 
    NA, 43965626L, 22499006L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The second dataframe that has the parent values from where the values can be picked is given as below, it is pretty big data

```
    fd1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 
1961L, 1962L, 1962L, 1962L, 1962L, 1962L, 1962L, 1962L, 1963L, 
1963L, 1963L, 1963L, 1963L, 1963L, 1963L, 1964L, 1964L, 1964L, 
1964L, 1964L, 1964L, 1964L, 1965L, 1965L, 1965L, 1965L, 1965L, 
1965L, 1965L, 1966L, 1966L, 1966L, 1966L, 1966L, 1966L, 1966L, 
1967L, 1967L, 1967L, 1967L, 1967L, 1967L, 1967L, 1968L, 1968L, 
1968L, 1968L, 1968L, 1968L, 1968L, 1969L, 1969L, 1969L, 1969L, 
1969L, 1969L, 1969L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 
1970L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1972L, 
1972L, 1972L, 1972L, 1972L, 1972L, 1972L, 1973L, 1973L, 1973L, 
1973L, 1973L, 1973L, 1973L, 1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 
1974L, 1974L, 1975L, 1975L, 1975L, 1975L, 1975L, 1975L, 1975L, 
1976L, 1976L, 1976L, 1976L, 1976L, 1976L, 1976L, 1977L, 1977L, 
1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1978L, 1978L, 1978L, 1978L, 
1978L, 1978L, 1978L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 
1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 
1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1999L, 
1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Area = c("USA", "Canada", "USSR", 
"Australia", "Argentina", "France", "Romania", "USA", "Canada", 
"Australia", "USSR", "Argentina", "France", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"USA", "Canada", "Australia", "USSR", "France", "Argentina", 
"Romania", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "Argentina", "France", 
"USSR", "Mexico", "USA", "Canada", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"France", "USSR", "Mexico", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "Argentina", 
"France", "USSR", "Romania", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "USSR", 
"Argentina", "France", "Romania", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", 
"France", "USSR", "Argentina", "Romania", "USA", "Canada", "France", 
"USSR", "Australia", "Argentina", "Germany", "USA", "Canada", 
"Australia", "USSR", "France", "Argentina", "Germany", "USA", 
"Canada", "Australia", "USSR", "France", "Argentina", "Netherlands", 
"USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", "USSR", "Argentina", 
"Netherlands", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "USSR", 
"Argentina", "Germany", "USA", "Canada", "France", "USSR", "Australia", 
"Argentina", "Hungary", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", 
"USSR", "Argentina", "Netherlands", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", 
"France", "Argentina", "Romania", "Netherlands", "USA", "Canada", 
"Australia", "France", "Argentina", "USSR", "Romania", "USA", 
"Canada", "Australia", "France", "Turkey", "Argentina", "USSR", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "USSR", 
"Belgium-Luxembourg", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", 
"Argentina", "USSR", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "USSR", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "USA", 
"Canada", "Australia", "France", "Argentina", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USSR", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"USSR", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"Germany", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", 
"Hungary", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Australia", "Canada", "France", "Argentina", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"Germany", "USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", "Argentina", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "Germany", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "Germany", 
"Saudi Arabia", "USA", "France", "Canada", "Australia", "Argentina", 
"Germany", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"Netherlands", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "Germany", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "Germany", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "USA", 
"France", "Canada", "Australia", "Argentina", "Kazakhstan", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", "Germany", "Argentina", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "USA", 
"Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "Germany", "Hungary", 
"USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", "Germany", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"Argentina", "USA", "Australia", "Canada", "France", "Argentina", 
"Germany", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"USA", "Canada", "Australia", "France", "Argentina", "Germany", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "USA", 
"France", "Australia", "Canada", "Argentina", "Germany", "Ukraine", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", "Kazakhstan", 
"Germany", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Argentina", 
"Germany", "Kazakhstan", "USA", "Australia", "France", "Canada", 
"Russia", "Argentina", "Ukraine", "USA", "France", "Canada", 
"Australia", "Russia", "Argentina", "Kazakhstan", "USA", "Australia", 
"Canada", "France", "Argentina", "Russia", "Germany", "USA", 
"France", "Canada", "Australia", "Argentina", "Russia", "Ukraine", 
"USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Russia", "Argentina", 
"Germany", "USA", "Canada", "Russia", "France", "Argentina", 
"Australia", "Kazakhstan", "USA", "France", "Canada", "Russia", 
"Argentina", "Australia", "Ukraine", "USA", "Canada", "France", 
"Russia", "Australia", "Ukraine", "Germany", "USA", "France", 
"Canada", "Australia", "Russia", "Germany", "Kazakhstan", "USA", 
"France", "Australia", "Canada", "Russia", "Argentina", "Germany", 
"USA", "Australia", "Canada", "France", "Russia", "Argentina", 
"Ukraine", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Australia", "Russia", 
"Germany", "Ukraine", "USA", "Canada", "Russia", "France", "Australia", 
"Germany", "Ukraine", "Canada", "USA", "Russia", "France", "Australia", 
"Ukraine", "Germany", "Russia", "USA", "Canada", "France", "Ukraine", 
"Australia", "Argentina", "Russia", "USA", "Australia", "Canada", 
"Ukraine", "France", "Argentina", "Russia", "Canada", "USA", 
"France", "Ukraine", "Australia", "Argentina"), Value = c(17168496L, 
9964000L, 4800600L, 4163800L, 1065537L, 1048500L, 280000L, 14136700L, 
8045900L, 5529000L, 4765200L, 2832340L, 1654500L, 211600L, 17470096L, 
10731200L, 4136000L, 4105600L, 2630300L, 1830656L, 410200L, 20574672L, 
13615200L, 6905300L, 3710010L, 2966500L, 2030500L, 575905L, 17700576L, 
11882350L, 6660584L, 5714700L, 4046000L, 1662600L, 684815L, 22483552L, 
14577370L, 5156788L, 5054666L, 3619955L, 2805300L, 864300L, 17474592L, 
9535232L, 6505912L, 5284000L, 2059732L, 2046566L, 1121600L, 16118222L, 
9246342L, 6498486L, 4613580L, 4355000L, 2422612L, 1176000L, 12102230L, 
6686393L, 5983065L, 5978800L, 4890817L, 2344662L, 817053L, 17444336L, 
10746250L, 6886084L, 4851900L, 3446386L, 2301756L, 1453638L, 
16215069L, 12885960L, 9088605L, 7605400L, 3357232L, 810932L, 
514380L, 21308080L, 13964494L, 8459044L, 5753122L, 3910600L, 
1640053L, 551934L, 37398000L, 12323961L, 7023102L, 5391031L, 
4198700L, 2970599L, 934360L, 25132960L, 10181328L, 7384438L, 
5293703L, 5128150L, 1726338L, 934472L, 30966720L, 11188944L, 
7860069L, 6280511L, 2681329L, 1758087L, 1536775L, 26536640L, 
10717744L, 7558718L, 7336089L, 3154591L, 1384600L, 905918L, 23825952L, 
14822056L, 7945143L, 5919521L, 5634583L, 2062000L, 1315200L, 
34096480L, 14432458L, 10948926L, 6394102L, 1921199L, 1608368L, 
1150000L, 33379040L, 11696434L, 7247388L, 6823720L, 4278852L, 
2600000L, 958439L, 35756128L, 17016320L, 14876378L, 9888599L, 
4494648L, 1270000L, 1054725L, 43908640L, 15495050L, 12591630L, 
10551501L, 3766401L, 1600000L, 1510880L, 40521632L, 19214576L, 
10912459L, 10634121L, 3800529L, 2354489L, 1633000L, 38491184L, 
21808048L, 13409314L, 10182443L, 8215277L, 1800000L, 1324132L, 
42242960L, 21091328L, 13616579L, 10534635L, 7244968L, 2175360L, 
1827993L, 24809616L, 17006752L, 16942640L, 15703855L, 9582881L, 
2002549L, 1886228L, 24555808L, 16108761L, 15957017L, 13367338L, 
4021418L, 3987244L, 2225051L, 30638016L, 22139728L, 14789431L, 
14219753L, 4192092L, 4121589L, 2310615L, 40499664L, 20087424L, 
14847453L, 12183063L, 3642577L, 3185451L, 2058139L, 36568800L, 
15089216L, 11274136L, 10449339L, 4322853L, 4080064L, 3278348L, 
27557024L, 17954496L, 17165168L, 11506710L, 5836660L, 4459887L, 
2529790L, 31088576L, 23260640L, 17264672L, 11943294L, 5511124L, 
4024325L, 2521798L, 33876960L, 23644752L, 17355168L, 8096933L, 
6071943L, 4764068L, 3975266L, 35665888L, 18259094L, 18210168L, 
9487424L, 5777230L, 4648000L, 3897550L, 30570900L, 21378004L, 
12730000L, 12650000L, 5524252L, 5172297L, 3494053L, 32420000L, 
16960000L, 16310000L, 7818000L, 6913286L, 3681597L, 2764541L, 
31150000L, 16520000L, 14567981L, 14550000L, 4199853L, 3674553L, 
3532042L, 25768091L, 19377867L, 18857913L, 14600399L, 8791336L, 
3861972L, 3645254L, 27003721L, 17701874L, 15231075L, 13732658L, 
10370581L, 4931668L, 4213126L, 28445452L, 18316504L, 16540263L, 
16158108L, 8796526L, 4665592L, 4525718L, 27830150L, 18771740L, 
18034056L, 17724364L, 11019021L, 4989634L, 4569373L, 25782618L, 
17658856L, 15621317L, 15542103L, 10790517L, 5710406L, 3022663L, 
24245829L, 14697182L, 13678411L, 12202573L, 10259275L, 9051610L, 
8303974L, 25429428L, 16366886L, 11703543L, 9503389L, 7587902L, 
6169213L, 5194873L, 31581449L, 18450822L, 15118679L, 14891804L, 
9976599L, 4672189L, 3926949L, 27178553L, 16022528L, 13924960L, 
13914503L, 10431146L, 10319594L, 6009481L, 23377178L, 18497809L, 
16580501L, 14975540L, 9704620L, 9697359L, 6105950L, 32946902L, 
17551674L, 14444108L, 14386449L, 9645491L, 6755804L, 6178065L, 
30093351L, 16292571L, 15781400L, 11720200L, 8772264L, 8278014L, 
7511300L, 21942248L, 19279098L, 16872217L, 16821195L, 14996065L, 
12882638L, 9687782L, 27629318L, 21081540L, 18394492L, 15888042L, 
11848321L, 8915328L, 5066453L, 32789893L, 20345934L, 17657181L, 
16335086L, 15185953L, 8411136L, 6168890L, 25769493L, 23535862L, 
17866820L, 16469022L, 16088832L, 11461359L, 8679388L, 33198288L, 
19808018L, 19638502L, 18001619L, 13796347L, 8223838L, 7762279L, 
25645749L, 24189370L, 22139263L, 20398724L, 18282773L, 10959156L, 
10543788L, 23610801L, 21268696L, 21234225L, 19815289L, 17053209L, 
13451830L, 10815210L, 25326784L, 24041586L, 19702348L, 18343653L, 
17920945L, 16148016L, 10266234L, 33025971L, 27299214L, 21985914L, 
21934799L, 17314278L, 15228664L, 13099133L, 43965626L, 22874184L, 
22499006L, 18940343L, 16373389L, 12352837L, 11724765L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-406L), groups = structure(list(Year = 1961:2018, .rows = structure(list(
    1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28, 29:35, 36:42, 43:49, 50:56, 57:63, 
    64:70, 71:77, 78:84, 85:91, 92:98, 99:105, 106:112, 113:119, 
    120:126, 127:133, 134:140, 141:147, 148:154, 155:161, 162:168, 
    169:175, 176:182, 183:189, 190:196, 197:203, 204:210, 211:217, 
    218:224, 225:231, 232:238, 239:245, 246:252, 253:259, 260:266, 
    267:273, 274:280, 281:287, 288:294, 295:301, 302:308, 309:315, 
    316:322, 323:329, 330:336, 337:343, 344:350, 351:357, 358:364, 
    365:371, 372:378, 379:385, 386:392, 393:399, 400:406), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have resized the dataframes to make the problem reproducible for better.

Comment: Without looking at the data frames, did you try merging?

Comment: no merging, `fd2` is derivative of `fd1` but some values are missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reshaping would make this easier. To maintain the same structure as your original data you can reshape it back. We can use `coalesce` to replace the missing values in `fd2` from `fd1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fd2 <- fd2 %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -Area, names_to = 'Year') %>%
        left_join(fd1 %>% mutate(Year = as.character(Year)), 
                 by = c('Year', 'Area'))  %>%
        mutate(value = coalesce(value, Value)) %>%
       select(-Value) %>%
       pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Above solution works. But, Any possiblity of using `which(is.na(fd2), arr.ind = T)` which if can return rowname and colname to be used for pulling values from `fd1`. That would be new and cool approach.

Comment: Maybe that is possible but that would be confusing I think.

Comment: I appreciate but I tried only not be duplicated, I thought it worthwhile giving a try, Thanks for your efforts and solution. New thing I learnt today is `coalesce`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can think by stepping aside from conventional skills driven thought process. I tried to write a code as below.

```
dd <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(fd2), arr.ind = T))

i = 1

for (i in 1:nrow(dd)){
    cc <- fd2$Area[dd[i,1]]
    rr <- names(fd2[dd[i,2]])
    vv <- with(fd1, fd1[(Year %in% rr) & Area %in% cc, ncol(fd1)])
    fd2[dd[i, 1], dd[i, 2]] <- vv
  }
```

It pulls the values from `fd1` and fixes into `fd2`.